# javascript confusing function calls and returns in Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript

I am reading the code of the dropzone.js and there are some function calls which totally does not make sense to me. I want some explaination.
I'll start at the `_processThumbnailQueue`

here the call is made to the `createThumnail()` with callback. 1) why is the callback call is in this immediate-calling-itself form. what does  content of this said function represent? Are they following the closure rules here??

Simply, the calls here and returns here are totally haywire.. i am getting lost and don't know what is being passed and what is returned.

```
Dropzone.prototype._processThumbnailQueue = function() {
  if (this._processingThumbnail || this._thumbnailQueue.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  this._processingThumbnail = true;
  return this.createThumbnail(this._thumbnailQueue.shift(), (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      _this._processingThumbnail = false;
      return _this._processThumbnailQueue();
    };
  })(this));
};

Dropzone.prototype.createThumbnail = function(file, callback) {
  var fileReader;
  fileReader = new FileReader;
  fileReader.onload = (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      if (file.type === "image/svg+xml") {
        _this.emit("thumbnail", file, fileReader.result);
        if (callback != null) {
          callback();
        }
        return;
      }
      return _this.createThumbnailFromUrl(file, fileReader.result, callback);
    };
  })(this);
  return fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

Dropzone.prototype.createThumbnailFromUrl = function(file, imageUrl, callback) {
  var img;
  img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      var canvas, ctx, resizeInfo, thumbnail, _ref, _ref1, _ref2, _ref3;
      file.width = img.width;
      file.height = img.height;
      resizeInfo = _this.options.resize.call(_this, file);
      if (resizeInfo.trgWidth == null) {
        resizeInfo.trgWidth = resizeInfo.optWidth;
      }
      if (resizeInfo.trgHeight == null) {
        resizeInfo.trgHeight = resizeInfo.optHeight;
      }
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = resizeInfo.trgWidth;
      canvas.height = resizeInfo.trgHeight;
      drawImageIOSFix(ctx, img, (_ref = resizeInfo.srcX) != null ? _ref : 0, (_ref1 = resizeInfo.srcY) != null ? _ref1 : 0, resizeInfo.srcWidth, resizeInfo.srcHeight, (_ref2 = resizeInfo.trgX) != null ? _ref2 : 0, (_ref3 = resizeInfo.trgY) != null ? _ref3 : 0, resizeInfo.trgWidth, resizeInfo.trgHeight);
      thumbnail = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      _this.emit("thumbnail", file, thumbnail);
      if (callback != null) {
        return callback();
      }
    };
  })(this);
  if (callback != null) {
    img.onerror = callback;
  }
  return img.src = imageUrl;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like the way that Dropzone code is written.

Yes, it uses closures, but it sets them up in the most clumsy and obfuscated way. There's no need for all those immediately executing function expressions, and the way the code switches between `this` and `_this` is a recipe for confusion.

I did a quick rewrite of the code to remove all this complication. I haven't tested this, but I believe it should do the same thing. See if this is a little easier to follow:

```
Dropzone.prototype._processThumbnailQueue = function() {
  var dz = this;
  if (dz._processingThumbnail || dz._thumbnailQueue.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  dz._processingThumbnail = true;
  return dz.createThumbnail(dz._thumbnailQueue.shift(), function() {
    dz._processingThumbnail = false;
    return dz._processThumbnailQueue();
  });
};

Dropzone.prototype.createThumbnail = function(file, callback) {
  var dz = this;
  var fileReader;
  fileReader = new FileReader;
  fileReader.onload = function() {
    if (file.type !== "image/svg+xml") {
      return dz.createThumbnailFromUrl(file, fileReader.result, callback);
    }
    dz.emit("thumbnail", file, fileReader.result);
    if (callback != null) {
      callback();
    }
  };
  return fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

Dropzone.prototype.createThumbnailFromUrl = function(file, imageUrl, callback) {
  var dz = this;
  var img;
  img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas, ctx, resizeInfo, thumbnail, _ref, _ref1, _ref2, _ref3;
    file.width = img.width;
    file.height = img.height;
    resizeInfo = dz.options.resize.call(dz, file);
    if (resizeInfo.trgWidth == null) {
      resizeInfo.trgWidth = resizeInfo.optWidth;
    }
    if (resizeInfo.trgHeight == null) {
      resizeInfo.trgHeight = resizeInfo.optHeight;
    }
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = resizeInfo.trgWidth;
    canvas.height = resizeInfo.trgHeight;
    drawImageIOSFix(ctx, img, (_ref = resizeInfo.srcX) != null ? _ref : 0, (_ref1 = resizeInfo.srcY) != null ? _ref1 : 0, resizeInfo.srcWidth, resizeInfo.srcHeight, (_ref2 = resizeInfo.trgX) != null ? _ref2 : 0, (_ref3 = resizeInfo.trgY) != null ? _ref3 : 0, resizeInfo.trgWidth, resizeInfo.trgHeight);
    thumbnail = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    dz.emit("thumbnail", file, thumbnail);
    if (callback != null) {
      return callback();
    }
  };
  if (callback != null) {
    img.onerror = callback;
  }
  return img.src = imageUrl;
};
```

As you can see, at the beginning of each function I set `dz` to `this` and then use `dz` consistently in the rest of the function. This is all that's needed to take advantage of closures.

Another simplification is to reverse the sense of the `if (file.type !== "image/svg+xml") ...` statement in `createThumbnail()`. This eliminates an entire level of nesting and makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks Michael Geary.. I was really confused as to why IEFE all the time?? Now that the code above is clear.. I will ask you one more question... WHEN TO USE IEFE???

Comment: Also according to my knowledge I thought that the callback in `createThumbnail` call is creating closure with the called function not from where it is called?